# Dynamically change values in drillthrough donut based on slicer selection

Tags: powerbi, donut-chart, drillthrough

I have different account types under a country, and those accounts have values(income earned). I want to create a drillthrough donut chart which shows all accounts for a country based on slicer selection.
Slicer has all the  country names?
I created a measure like:

```
cal = CALCULATE(SUM('ACC'[California]),'ACC_Copy'[Country]="California")
```

but this doesn't work because drillthrough donut only takes 1 value at a time.
How do I change it dynamically?

All your help will be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: How are your tables structured? Do you have a column for each country? which filed is used in the slicer?

Comment: @Giovanni Luisotto yes, I have a column for each state-CA,FL,ID etc. And slicer will have names of state.

Comment: Then I highly suggest you unpivot those columns in order to obtain the columns "Country" and "Value", this will work way better in PowerBI and will probably solve your problem. Also, it will be easier to help you if you post some sample data and explain the structure of your data model?